# Where do I get google location data for this autocomplete feature?

Tags: javascript, html, geolocation

I am confused about which location service api to query to get an autocomplete widget working like they have at zimride: http://www.zimride.com/

What are these guys using that says powered by Google?

I need local national data for India but not google maps at the moment. Should I be looking at the places api? I am looking for an html5/javascript implementation for my mobile web app.

Comment: Take a look at https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geolocation

Comment: This shows a maps implmentation, how do I get an autocomplete for place names when user types in where he is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google offers a "Places Autocomplete API". The documentation is at https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/autocomplete

Comment: Ya - kinda found a fiddle for this too -http://jsfiddle.net/amit_e/E8UPy/

This is using the places api right?

Answer (score 1):

I'm doing the same in RSA.

Check out:

https://github.com/ddidier/address_picker-rails

Works perfect!